# Default visualisation keras progress bar neural net

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-lab

I come to you because I have a visualisation problem in my Jupyter-lab.

When I run a neural network in a cell of the jupyter-lab the progress bar works but, the text print every iteration. The cell :

```py
    seed = 1337
    np.random.seed(seed)
    loss_         = "categorical_crossentropy"
    optimizer_    = "rmsprop"

    sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
    x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation=activation_1, padding="same")(embedded_sequences)
    x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
    x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation=activation_1, padding="same")(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
    x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation=activation_1, padding="same")(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(3)(x)  # global max pooling
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation=activation_1)(x)
    preds = Dense(len(set(df.y)), activation=activation_2)(x)

    model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
    model.compile(loss=loss_,
              optimizer=optimizer_,
              metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy])

    # happy learning!
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
          epochs=25, batch_size=128, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor, checkpoint])
```

The result that I obtain is like this :

[image: Text iteration of progress bar]

I have updated the different packages to have the latest version in my anaconda environment.

How can I fix the visualisation of the progress bar ?

Best,

Chris

Comment: Try manually adding the parameter `verbose=1` in `model.fit()`

Comment: Infact the default value is `verbose=1`, you can even try `verbose=2` which doesn't show the progress bar, but shows the changing values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies, so verbose=1 doen't change anything and verbose=2 just print anything

Comment: BTW, is this in the notebook or are you redirecting the output to a file. In case of redirecting the output to the file, it is always the case.

Comment: No it,s inside the notebook and the "console" each time the iteration print the results like the picture